# What is meant by lexicographical byte

Tags: java, lexicographic

I tried searching this word but unable to get proper answer...
Is `lexicographical` means sorting alphabetically **OR** if two or more parameters share the same name, they are sorted by their value.

Thanks for your help!!!!.....

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order here.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the numbers 2,3,4 and 23 numerically, you get 2,3,4,23

If you sort them lexicographically, you get 2,23,3,4

For example, the output of `ls -l`is sorted lexicographically, therefore you see

```
file2
file23
file3
file4
```

Instead of

```
file2
file3
file4
file23
```

Answer (score 0):

`lexicographical order` stands for the way you order data (sort) - like in dictionary (alphabetically).

That is, in java, if you want to sort Strings you just order them using `a.compareTo(b) < 0`. If you have `String[N] strings` it will be lexicographically sorted if the following holds:

- `strings[0].compareTo(strings[1]) < 0`
- `strings[1].compareTo(strings[2]) < 0`
- `...`
- `strings[n-2].compareTo(strings[n-1]) < 0`

Read more on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Comment: Means alphabtically ?

Comment: I am not asking about the code please clear my terminology related to lexicographical

Comment: In case of strings it's the same as alphabetically. But lexicographical sort is generalized not only for strings.